# Mongodb $subtract difference between 2 dates is in ms?

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning Mongodb and have a question about subtracting one date from another.  Here is one document in the trips database:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("572bb8222b288919b68abf5a"),
  'start station id': 476,
  'start station name': 'E 31 St & 3 Ave',
  'end station id': 498,
  'end station name': 'Broadway & W 32 St',
  bikeid: 17827,
  usertype: 'Subscriber',
  'birth year': 1969,
  'start station location': { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -73.97966069, 40.74394314 ] },
  'end station location': { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -73.98808416, 40.74854862 ] },
  'start time': ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:45.000Z"),
  'stop time': ISODate("2016-01-01T00:07:04.000Z")
}
```

From what I am learning, when you subtract one date from another, you get a return value in ms.  I am subtracting the start time from the stop time to get the total duration of the trip. I can see from the document that the total duration of the trip is 6 hours and 19 minutes, which is 22,740,000 ms. However, when using `$subtract` on the two dates, I get a return value of `Long("379000")`  My query looks like this:

```
db.trips.aggregate([{
  $project:{
    "_id":0, 
    "start time":1, 
    "stop time":1, 
    "trip duration":{
      $subtract:["$stop time", "$start time"]
    }
  }
}])
```

and the result is:

```
{
  'start time': ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:45.000Z"),
  'stop time': ISODate("2016-01-01T00:07:04.000Z"),
  'trip duration': Long("379000")
}
```

Why does the value appear as `Long("379000")` and why is the number of milliseconds different from the actual difference in milliseconds between the two dates?  How should this query be written to return the actual time in milliseconds (which is 22740000) so that I can easily convert it to minutes/hours?

Comment: 379000 is actually valid value. Try by your self https://www.onlineconversion.com/days_between_advanced.htm

Comment: @AminCheloh Thank you.  I see my problem now.  I was looking at the date incorrectly. The difference between them is 6 minutes and 19 seconds, not 6 hours and 19 minutes.  Thank you!

Comment: Is the difference always less than one day?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question: Yes, it is in milliseconds (1s = 1000ms).

---

Extra (I think it can be helpful):

Put custom function which can convert milliseconds to hours, minutes, seconds:

```js
db.trips.aggregate([{
  $project:{
    "_id":0, 
    "start time":1, 
    "stop time":1, 
    "trip duration":{
      $function:
               {
                  body: function(starTime, stopTime) {
                    var start = starTime.getTime();
                    var stop = stopTime.getTime();
                    
                    var diff = parseInt((stop - start)/1000); // seconds

                    var hours = parseInt(diff / 3600);
                    diff -= hours * 3600;
                    
                    
                    var minutes = parseInt(diff / 60);
                    diff -= minutes * 60;
                    
                    seconds = diff;

                    return {hours, minutes, seconds};
                  },
                  args: [ "$start time", "$stop time"],
                  lang: "js"
               }
    }
  }
}])
```

works like charm:

[image: function aggregate]

Comment: A bit overkill, I would say. Simply use function [$dateDiff](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I agree, but dateDiff does not give separately hours, minutes and seconds. I checked mongodb man pages and could not find method which will return desired result as in my screenshot.